# Retrieving JSON Data From a Private Google Spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-sheets-api

I have searched high and low, but I cannot find an answer to my question.

Is it possible to retrieve data from a private Google spreadsheet in JSON format using php?

I know how to authenticate to access the spreadsheet.

When I use this url: `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$key/od6/private/full`

I get results in xml, but when I try to add "`?alt=json`" no content is returned.

Is it possible to get the results returned as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use as a gateway between your GSheet and a custom JSON web API such as: https://apispark.com/docs/tutorials/google-spreadsheet